# LXDE (Openbox): add "resize corner" to the window

Tags: openbox, lxde, theme

I am using LXDE (Openbox). Every time I need to re-size my window, I have to position my mouse carefully to grab the thin window frame until my mouse cursor changes and I can re-size the window.

I remember seeing in other window managers a "resize corner" in the bottom right corner of the window, which can easily be grabbed to resize the window diagonally.

Does anything like this exist in LXDE (Openbox) ?
How can I add it ?
Can it be configured in `~/.local/share/themes/theme/openbox-3/themerc` ?

Comment: you should start doing stuff with keyboard, setting up the lubuntu-rc.xml file. there are good instructions out there already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, something *like* it currently exists, but it is not the same resize grip in the corner that is used in gtk themes. Something like that would need to be coded into openbox.

**Add a Handle**
In your themerc for the theme you are using, you can set `window.handle.width` to a number of pixels and handle will appear below the window[1](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Themes#window.inactive.grip.bg). The handle includes diagonal resizing tools in the left and right corners. Unfortunately, this method does take up a bit more real estate than the gtk style corner grip.

For example, in your themerc, this would create a 6 pixel wide handle:

`window.handle.width: 6`

> Specifies the size of the window handle. The window handle is the
>   piece of decorations on the bottom of windows. A value of 0 means that
>   no handle is shown.

To activate changes made to the theme, run `openbox --reconfigure`.

**Change Border Width**
You may also change the `border.width` setting in your themerc to make the window border wider. This increases the area you can drag, but also increases the visual border of the window, so again you are sacrificing screen real estate which sucks.

**Drag with Alt + Right-Click**
You can position the cursor anywhere over the window, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and hold the right mouse button to resize the nearest window edge. This includes corners. The only downside here is that this requires a two hand operation. You may be able to create a custom key binding that is preferred.

The mouse binding for resizing is in `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` or whichever the appropriate rc file is in the `~/.config/openbox/` directory and looks like this:

```
  <mousebind button="A-Right" action="Drag">
    <action name="Resize"/>
  </mousebind>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Openbox themes, edit `themerc` for your given themes choice, and change the following to something like:

`border.width: 10`

These are located in `/usr/share/themes/THEMENAME/openbox-3/themerc` and can be duplicated and configured under `.local/share/themes/THEMENAME/openbox-3/themerc` as you mention.

The Alt+Right-Click is a handy keyboard/mouse combo to grab any corner or edge without being approximately near it.